# PHP - 127.0.0.1 not working but localhost does

Tags: aptana3

I am using Aptana 3.22 with XAMPP. When I run a PHP file, the url shows as `http://127.0.0.1:8020/somefile.php` and the PHP code is just listed in the browser. However, if I replace `127.0.0.1:8020` with `localhost` it all works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think that to vague to be able to get a good answer, in that there's too many variables that could affect it, I'd hazard a guess that localhost doesn't really point to localhost:8020 but rather just localhost:80 (the standard), so you might be seeing a different site.

Answer (score 0):

Go to run configurations select Web Browser then choose which browser you want to use. Then in the main tab find use base URL and click on it. Enter `http://localhost/` and make sure that you check the append project name.

Make sure that your index page's name is index.php and try running it. Hope this helps.